# vbscript Remove mapped drive if the drive letter and path matches

Tags: vbscript

Here is the vbscript  that I have which should remove the netwrok drive if it matches the letter and the path but it does not work properly and the array shows 13 mapped drives which I only have 5 on my computer. Doesnt it suppose to check all the available mapped drives on the user's mapped computer?

```
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Set objNet = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Network") 

Set objExec = objShell.Exec("net use ") 
strMaps = LCase(objExec.StdOut.ReadAll)
MapArray=split(strMaps,CHR(10))

for x=1 to ubound(MapArray) 
    if instr(MapArray(x),"W:") AND instr(mapArray(x),"\\path\folder$") then 
        objNet.RemoveNetworkDrive "W:",true,true
    end if

    if instr(MapArray(x),"U:") AND instr(mapArray(x),"\\path\folder$") then
            objNet.RemoveNetworkDrive "U:"
    end if  

next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enumerate network drives.

```
Set NetDrives = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network").EnumNetworkDrives
For X = 0 to NetDrives.Count -1 Step 2
    MsgBox NetDrives(x) & " " & NetDrives(x+1)
Next
```

To do what you want. We don't test then do usually. We do and test what happened. Testing most things usually takes up almost the same resources as doing.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WshNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "Y:"
Msgbox err.description
```

Again anything involving files and registry (because users delete) and networks or internet (because by nature are unreliable) should use error handling.